# Why this function getElementsByClassName not work on IE7 ,8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Why this function `getElementsByClassName` not work on IE7 ,8 ?

i think cause my issue from

```
var decimal_id_name = document.getElementsByClassName('decimal')[z_decimal].id
```

How to apply for work on IE7, 8 ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Fp4sJ/828/

To test , When user `press button`, It's will alert id name of input.

```
<form method="post" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<input type="text" class="decimal" id="number0" size="20" name="number[]">
<input type="text" class="decimal" id="number1" size="20" name="number[]">
<input type="text" class="decimal" id="number2" size="20" name="number[]">
<input type="text" class="decimal" id="number3" size="20" name="number[]">
<input type="text" class="decimal" id="number4" size="20" name="number[]">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkform ( form )
{
    function getElementsByClassName(node, classname) {
        var a = [];
        var re = new RegExp('(^| )'+classname+'( |$)');
        var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
            if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
        return a;
    }
    var list_decimal = getElementsByClassName(document.body,'decimal');


    for (z_decimal = 0; z_decimal < list_decimal.length; ++z_decimal) {
        var decimal_id_name = document.getElementsByClassName('decimal')[z_decimal].id
        alert(decimal_id_name);
    }
    return false ;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is not supported in IE7-8

http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName

You should try to polyfill it

https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName
function `getElementsByClassName` was introduced in IE9, so it won't work in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` is not supported by IE8, only IE9 and above. You can use polyfills to get the functionality, or you can use `document.querySelectorAll(selector)` which is a much more robust function. The parameter `selector` is anything the IE8's CSS selector can do.